# CDK generating empty targets for CfnCrawler

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm using CDK Python API to define a Glue crawler, however, the CDK generated template contains empty 'Targets' block in the Crawler resource.

I've not been able to find an example to emulate. I've tried varying the definition of the targets object, but the object definition seems to be ignored by CDK.

```py
from aws_cdk import cdk

BUCKET='poc-1-bucket43879c71-5uabw2rni0cp'

class PocStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, app: cdk.App, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(app, id)

        from aws_cdk import (
            aws_iam as iam,
            aws_glue as glue,
            cdk
        )

        glue_role = iam.Role(
            self, 'glue_role',
            assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal('glue.amazonaws.com'),
            managed_policy_arns=['arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole']
        )

        glue_crawler = glue.CfnCrawler(
            self, 'glue_crawler',
            database_name='db',
            role=glue_role.role_arn,
            targets={"S3Targets": [{"Path": f'{BUCKET}/path/'}]},
        )
```

I expect the generated template to contain a valid 'targets' block with a single S3Target. However, `cdk synth` outputs a template with empty Targets in the AWS::Glue::Crawler resource:

```
  gluecrawler:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties:
      DatabaseName: db
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - glueroleFCCAEB57
          - Arn
      Targets: {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Resolved, thanks to a clever colleague!
Changing "S3Targets" to "s3Targets", and "Path" to "path" resolved the issue. See below.

> Hi Bob,
>
> When I use typescript, the following works for me:
>
> ```
> new glue.CfnCrawler(this, 'glue_crawler', {
>       databaseName: 'db',
>       role: glue_role.roleArn,
>       targets: {
>         s3Targets: [{ path: "path" }]
>       }
>     }
> ```
>
> When I used Python, the following appears working too:
>
> ```
> glue_crawler = glue.CfnCrawler(
>             self, 'glue_crawler',
>             database_name='db',
>             role=glue_role.role_arn,
>             targets={
>                 "s3Targets": [{ "path": f'{BUCKET}/path/'}]
>             },
>         )
> ```
>
> In Typescript, TargetsProperty is an interface with s3Targets as a property. And in 
>   s3Targets, path is a property as well. I guess during the JSII transformation, it forces 
>   us to use the same names in Python instead of the initial CFN resource names.

Answer (score 3):

A more general way to approach this problem is to dig inside the `cdk` library in 2 steps:

1.

```
from aws_cdk import aws_glue
print(aws_glue.__file__)
(.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_cdk/aws_glue/__init__.py)
```

2. Go to that file and see how the mapping/types are defined. As of 16 Aug 2020, you find

```
@jsii.data_type(
    jsii_type="@aws-cdk/aws-glue.CfnCrawler.TargetsProperty",
    jsii_struct_bases=[],
    name_mapping={
        "catalog_targets": "catalogTargets",
        "dynamo_db_targets": "dynamoDbTargets",
        "jdbc_targets": "jdbcTargets",
        "s3_targets": "s3Targets",
    }
)
```

I found that the `lowerCamelCase` always work, while the pythonic `snake_case` does not.